# ./ Dot Slash not working to execute Shell Scripts

Tags: linux, shell, unix, path

I'm definitely a command line novice.  I have recently lost the ability to execute shell scripts using

```
./script.sh
```

I am still able to execute shell scripts using:

```
sh script.sh
```

My $PATH is as follows:

```
/Users/goodguy/.pyenv/shims:/Users/goodguy/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Users/goodguy/.rvm/bin
```

I am using MacOS.  I'd appreciate any insight into what I may be doing wrong

Comment: Perhaps it doesn't have the executable flag set. Check with `ls -lart script.sh` and look for `x`. You can set it to executable using `chmod +x script.sh`

Comment: Perhaps `. ./script.sh` will work too. Here the first dot stands for `source`, what will (try to) run the lines in your script without starting a new shell. The second dot is the current directory.

Comment: @MatthewDarnell That was it.  I tried running the above with sudo and it still wasn't working.  I figured that if I could execute using 'sh script.sh' -- meant it was executable, but didn't realize I had to set a flag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can run command     chmod 755 script.sh

and then run the script with ./script.sh